# Replace mulitiple line using CMD

Tags: powershell, replace, cmd, find

I am trying to create a batch file which will conver all files in a folder with .html folder to .txt, find and replace text and rever back the .txt file to .html. The HTML file contain this line of code

```
                      `$(".screenshot").click(function () {
                            $(".ui-background").show();
                            $(this)
                                .clone()
                                .appendTo($('body'))
                                .addClass("full");
        });`
```

And I will like to replace it with

```
$("img.screenshot").addClass("fulldisplay");
$(".fulldisplay").css('float', 'left');
$(".fulldisplay").css('position', 'relative');
$(".fulldisplay").css('width', '100%');
$(".fulldisplay").css('height', 'auto');
```

Using ren cmd line i was able to convert the HTML file to .Txt so that I can search for this string and replace it with required one. But when it comes to find and replace nothing worked for me. I tried to use

```
powershell -Command "(gc C:\Users\IVIS\Downloads\m2test.txt) -replace '$(".screenshot").click(function(){$(".ui-background").show();$(this).clone().appendTo($('body')).addClass("full");});','$("img.screenshot").addClass("fulldisplay");
            $(".fulldisplay").css('float', 'left');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('position', 'relative');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('width', '100%');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('height', 'auto');'| Out-File C:\myFile.txt"
```

and few other things but nothing seems to be working. I also tried to use `fnr.exe` that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you are having with PowerShell is that -Replace uses RegEx matching, so your search string would have to be escaped for RegEx in order for it to work. What I think would work better for you is to make a script in PowerShell, and either run it directly or call the script from your batch file. I would do something like this:

```
Param([String]$Dir='.')
$Seek=(@'
                      `$(".screenshot").click(function () {
                            $(".ui-background").show();
                            $(this)
                                .clone()
                                .appendTo($('body'))
                                .addClass("full");
        });
'@).trim()
$NewText=(@'
$("img.screenshot").addClass("fulldisplay");
            $(".fulldisplay").css('float', 'left');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('position', 'relative');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('width', '100%');
            $(".fulldisplay").css('height', 'auto');
'@).trim()
Get-ChildItem "$Dir\*.html" | ForEach{
    $FilePath=$_.FullName
    (Get-Content $_.FullName -ReadCount 0) -replace [RegEx]::Escape($Seek), $NewText|Out-File $FilePath
}
```

Then you can call it from your batch file and just pass a folder path and it will process all of the HTML files in that folder.

Comment: Hi I really appriciate your quick reply but I am new to this powershell and still trying to understand it. So I made little change accoordly like change Param([String]$Dir='.') with ([String]$Dir='C:\MD\Dev\Test\Result') as the file is in chile of this path. and canged the Get-ChildItem "$Dir\*.html" to Get-ChildItem "$Dir\*.txt" as i already coverted the file from html to .txt but I dont know what to do with $FilePath=$_.FullName (My file name is AutoTestresult.txt) so I relaceed the Fullname with the filename but didnt work. Am I doing anything wrong?